# How to make corrections to a subscription invoice

Tags: python, stripe-payments

Let's say I have created a subscription for a customer in the Stripe Dashboard but made a mistake. I didn't realize my mistake until after the invoice was created. I now have an invoice in `draft` state with (for example) an incorrect line item. What are my options for correcting this before (or after) it goes to the customer?

- I can update the invoice state from `draft` to `open` (via the `finalize_invoice` API call), which allows me to void the invoice
- I can cancel the subscription and start over

If I void the invoice, I cannot see any way to re-invoice them for the period which was voided—am I missing something? This would be handy.

Is there another option I'm not aware of besides cancelling the subscription?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the invoice has been created you can no longer edit the line items. In this case if the invoice is a one-off and still in the `draft` state you'd want to [delete the draft](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/delete) and start over.

In the case of the subscription having the wrong items, you could either delete it and start over entirely or [update the items](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-items), delete/void the invoice and send a [one-off invoice](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/invoices/create) to replace the deleted one.

If you decide to go down the "create a new subscription with the correct items" route, you could then [backdate](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-backdate_start_date) the new subscription to match the start date of the deleted subscription.